# d3.js table restrict mouse click to certain column cell

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I attempt to use d3 table to manage data.
I searched the d3 with table,

you can click column to sort the [table](http://jsfiddle.net/younyzhU/q6LE6/5/).

Now I need to add some functions to cells in certain column.

```
var jsonData = [
{ "id": 3, "name": "Richy", "male": true, "born": "Sun May 05 2013", "amount": 12000},
{ "id": 1, "name": "Susi", "male": false, "born": "Mon May 13 2013", "amount": 2000},
{ "id": 2, "name": "Patrick", "male": true, "born": "Thu Jun 06 2013", "amount": 17000},
{ "id": 4, "name": "Lorenz", "male": true, "born": "Thu May 09 2013", "amount": 15000},
{ "id": 5, "name": "Christina", "male": false, "born": "Mon Jul 01 2013", "amount": 16000}
];
```

Fro example, If I need to add mouse click to `name` column,  However, If I do like below, all the other column will also have this function. Any suggestions?

```
// create cells
var td = tr.selectAll("td").data(function(d){return d3.values(d);});    
td.enter().append("td")
.text(function(d) {return d;}).on("click", function(d){
alert(d);
});
```

Another similar question, for certain cell of certain column, I want to style them, how should I do?
I attempt to detect the column by `i` index, but when the `jsonData` is changed, I need to find i.
Actually, for certain column, they `key` is the same.

Comment: In the `click` handler, check which column is being clicked (using the data).

Comment: thanks, the data just has value, I can not find the key. I can use i index, but if data changes I need to find name is in which column

Comment: If you use `d3.entries` instead of `d3.values`, you get access to the key as well: http://jsfiddle.net/q6LE6/6/

Comment: great, thanks. d3.entries is really a good feature to keep keys.